# Problema en java (windowBuilder)

Tags: java, java-swing, interfaz-gráfica, windowbuilder

Mi programa en Java se compone de diferentes paneles, los cuales se van haciendo visibles o no en funcion de la opcion del menu seleccionada, pero al iniciar el programa al pasar el cursor por el panel que aparece por defecto, **se muestran los botones de otros paneles**, solo me ocurre al iniciar.

He probado a crear un panel vacio y hacerlo visible unicamente a el al iniciar pero no funciona.

Comment: Hola, puedes echar un vistazo al [tour] y [ask] para [edit] tu pregunta.

Comment: Arreglado gracias a todos amijos :)

Comment: [Te pueden votar negativamente porque sin código, es difícil ayudarte](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2875/)